# How can I display the event table(author) from User(username)? (Android studio using firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tou1D.png)I created two table

1. Users , with fields

   id

   username
2. event, with fields

   event_name

   event_date

   author

I would like to display the author name is based on the Users(username)

So I saved the author is the Users table (id).

If I modify the value of Users(username), the value of event(author)
will be change. Thank you

I tried to add

```
User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

event_author.setText(user.getUsername());
```

into mUserDatabase,

but textViewEventAuthor had not display any words.

```
public class EventList extends ArrayAdapter {

    private Activity context;
    private List<Event> eventList;



    DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseEvents;


    public EventList(Activity context, List<Event> eventList) {
        super(context, R.layout.event_list_view, eventList);
        this.context = context;
        this.eventList = eventList;




    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        databaseEvents = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("events");


        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();


        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_list_view,null, true);
        TextView event_name = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewEventName);
        TextView event_date = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewEventDate);
        TextView event_author = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewEventAuthor);


        Event event = eventList.get(position);



        event_name.setText(event.getEvent_name());
        event_date.setText(event.getEvent_date());
        event_author.setText(event.getAuthor());








        // ======================================================================//
        mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                event_author.setText(user.getUsername());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        // ======================================================================//


        return listViewItem;

    }
}
```

I expect the output is

```
lunch

25-6-2019

Louis
```

But now, my output is

```
lunch

25-6-2019

dNcgMLa4vTb9Zin2LrCr8mGr8Vp1
```

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add a JSON file or at least a screenshot of it.

Comment: I uploaded my firebase database screenshot thank you

Comment: I would like to update the event's author when I  changed the Users's username name
Since I am using the login user to create a new event

Comment: Which `username` do you want to change? The one within `Users/uid` ot the one within `events/dimsum`?

Comment: I'm affraid I didn'd understand you. Can you please answer again the question in my last comment?

Comment: I would like to change the dimsum's username
In my listView now
it will show 
dimsum
6-6-2019
louis
but, how can I change the event --> dimsum --> Mr.Louis when I changed the Users username(louis) to username(Mr.Louis) too?